# What is the point of a valuation dataset

Tags: algorithm, validation, testing, machine-learning, training-data

another machine learning term that confuses me: validation set. I've read a few documents about this, and i have been wondering, is the validation set **only** necessary when there are multiple choices of algorithms to use? And if not, then what is the role of hyperparamter tuning? 
I'd very grateful for your explanation. Thank you in advance.